# How would I upgrade systemd?

Tags: systemd

I read today that systemd has been updated to version 220 over on [It Runs On Linux](http://www.itrunsonlinux.com/desktopos/systemd-v220-released/). I was wondering a couple of things not included in the article and pertaining specifically to ubuntu 15.04.

1. As the title states, how would I update systemd? It downloads as a tar.xz file, so would I just open up terminal and do a `tar -xvzf systemd-220.tar.xz`?
2. Would it fix the "starting version 219" system stalls on boot? I figured out how to fix the ACPI part of the common error that comes with nvidia drivers but I still get that hang. Eventually my system boots but it takes sometimes upwards of a minute to get into the GUI.

Thanks in advance for any info

Comment: I'd strongly discourage from messing with it, as upgrading will likely breake more than it might fix. Make sure you have a recovery strategy before proceeding. ...possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: `systemd` is very core to your system and ships naturally, starting with version **15.04**.  It is highly recommended that you update when updates are available through `apt`.   Have you tried updating via apt?  Is there an underlying issue you're trying to resolve that makes you want this version of `systemd`?

Comment: I haven't tried to update via anything yet since I don't have remote access set up on my system and have been at work all day so far. I will try that first when I get home. The issue I was hoping to fix is the "starting version 219" hang that a lot of people have been getting. All the answers I've read to fix that have not worked for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As already pointed out by @mikewhatever and @earthmeLon you **really** shouldn't mess around with this.

But if you really want to (make sure you've backups!), the best way to go would be with the `uupdate` script from `devscripts`. Run the following commands to install all necessary dependencies

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential devscripts
$ sudo apt-get build-dep systemd
```

Next download and extract the source tar-balls

```
$ mkdir systemd
$ cd systemd/
$ wget http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/systemd-220.tar.xz
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_219-7ubuntu3.dsc
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_219.orig.tar.xz
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_219-7ubuntu3.debian.tar.xz

$ tar xvJf systemd_219.orig.tar.xz 
$ cd systemd-219/
$ tar xvJf ../systemd_219-7ubuntu3.debian.tar.xz
```

Finally you can create a new source dir with `uupdate`, build `.deb` files and install them

```
$ uupdate ../systemd-220.tar.xz 220
$ cd ../systemd-220
$ dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
$ cd ..
$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: I'm making yours as answer because it was the most in depth. Basically unless it updates through apt-get dist-upgrade don't try it unless I want to risk bricking my system, but if I do here's how. Thank you.